# VS Code keeps using single quotes for string even after settings update

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, string-formatting, quotes

How could I configure VS Code to make it change all the single quotes to double quotes whenever I format a document? I searched in my settings for the `quotes` keyword and selected the double quotes everywhere I could:

[image]
[image]
[image]

But the result is that no quotes are changed on file formatting. I.e. the single quotes stay single and the double quotes stay double after formatting.

I am talking about .js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have prettier installed it seems (based off your options in the your screenshot), and that is probably overriding your settings.  You may see something like this in the prettier output when you save/format:

```
["INFO" - 9:28:24 AM] Formatting file:///c%3A/dev/GitHub/project/src/root.tsx
["INFO" - 9:28:24 AM] Using config file at 'c:\dev\GitHub\project\.prettierrc'
["INFO" - 9:28:24 AM] Using ignore file (if present) at c:\dev\GitHub\project\src\.prettierignore
["INFO" - 9:28:24 AM] File Info:
{
  "ignored": false,
  "inferredParser": "typescript"
}
["INFO" - 9:28:24 AM] Detected local configuration (i.e. .prettierrc or .editorconfig), VS Code configuration will not be used
["INFO" - 9:28:24 AM] Prettier Options:
{
  "filepath": "c:\\dev\\GitHub\\project\\src\\root.tsx",
  "parser": "typescript",
  "useTabs": false,
  "printWidth": 120,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "endOfLine": "auto",
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "bracketSameLine": false
}
["INFO" - 9:28:24 AM] Formatting completed in 0.061ms.
```

Note the `"singleQuote": true,` part, as well as the `Detected local configuration (i.e. .prettierrc or .editorconfig)` in the output.  If you have a .prettierrc file, modify it and set `singleQuote` to `false`.  Save the file, restart Visual Studio Code, and then try again.

Comment: I had a `.prettierrc` file which I was not even aware off and which was overriding the settings. Removing that file solved the issue. The file was reported in the Prettier output.

Comment: @manymanymore removing that file probably makes it fallback to using VS Code's settings, which seems to be what you are after anyway.  In our repo's, this file is checked in I believe, so deleting it would impact other developers, but if that's not your setup, you'll be fine!